# How can I have a submit button (in grails) update a specific target frame?

Tags: grails, submit, frame, target

I'd like to use something like the "`update=`" parameter of a `<g:remoteLink>` with a `<g:actionSubmit>`, so that when the submit button is clicked, it will update a specific target. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using a `<g:remoteForm>`, this allows you to specify an `update` parameter. Found at: http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html section 6.7.1.3

Comment: Any attribute that's explicitly used by the tag is passed through to the html.

Comment: Another option I've discovered is to use a `<g:submitToRemote>`